# Inserting JSON schema into U-SQL table

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-data-lake, u-sql

I want to insert JSON schema for my U-SQL table in DataLake Analysts tool. Here is my JSON schema

```
DECLARE @json string=  "{
        "definitions": {},
        "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-06/schema#",
        "$id": "http://getIQOS.com/IQOSAbandonedCartV1.json",
        "title": "CE:I:ORD:ABC",
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
            "altriaOrchestrated": {
                "$id": "/properties/altriaOrchestrated",
                "type": "integer",
                "title": "Altria Orchestrated",
                "description": "Specifies whether the AT object is being called by Core Services (1) or from an outside source (0)",
                "default": 0,
                "enum": [
                    0, 1
                ],
                "examples": [
                    0, 1
                ],
                "minimum": 0,
                "maximum": 1
            },
        "required": [
            "altriaOrchestrated",
            "initiativeName",
            "date",
            "inventory"
        ]
     }"
```

I am getting below error and can not understand what error it is. I my development halted because of this issue.

```
 AGG ALL AND ARRAY BETWEEN BIGINT BIT BINARY BY COLUMNSET CREATED CSHARP CURRENT DATETIME DATETIME2 DECIMAL EXISTS FILE FLOAT FOLLOWING GROUP IN INT IS LENGTH LCID MAP MAX MODIFIED MONEY NULL NVARCHAR OR OVER PARTITION PRECEDING REAL SMALLINT SQL STRUCT TINYINT UNBOUNDED UNIQUEIDENTIFIER VARBINARY VARCHAR WITHIN string-literal numeric-literal character-literal punctuation-mark identifier quoted-identifier reserved-identifier variable system-variable '[' ']' '(' '{' '}' '=' '.' '*' ':' '?' '<' '>'
```

Answer (score 0):

Per my testing, you could leverage the double quote, backslash as follows to declare your json string parameter.

```html
DECLARE @json string ="{"+
        "\"definitions\": {},"+
        "\"$schema\": \"http://json-schema.org/draft-06/schema#\","+
        "\"$id\": \"http://getIQOS.com/IQOSAbandonedCartV1.json\","+
        "\"title\": \"CE:I:ORD:ABC\","+
        "\"type\": \"object\","+
        "\"properties\": {"+
            "\"altriaOrchestrated\": {}"+
        "}"+
"}";
```

Also, you could leverage Verbatim C# string literals that simplify the handling of such characters by prepending the @ character in front of the starting double quote of the string. For your json string, you could declare it as follows:

```html
DECLARE @json string =@"{
        ""definitions"": {},
        ""$schema"": ""http://json-schema.org/draft-06/schema#"",
        ""$id"": ""http://getIQOS.com/IQOSAbandonedCartV1.json"",
        ""title"": ""CE:I:ORD:ABC"",
        ""type"": ""object"",
        ""properties"": {
           ""altriaOrchestrated"": {}
        }
}";
```

**Note:**

> The maximal size of a column of type string is 128kB in U-SQL (based on the byte count of the string value represented in UTF-8 encoding).

Details you could follow [Textual Types and Literals](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-analytics/u-sql/textual-types-and-literals).